# JQuery Accordion issues in IE8, works great locally but not on the server

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

We are working on: http://www.ftj.com/carrier-information

If you choose "Transamerica Corporation" in IE8 you will see some height issues.  However, when you resize your IE window the page seems to auto correct without a refresh.

When we run this locally there are no issues what-so-ever.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that our browser settings were set to compatibility mode...  Not an IE8 issue at all.

Answer (score -1):

Issue may be on this JS file:

> "src="/CarrierInformation.js">"

change with this piece of code:

> **$(document).ready(function(){**
>
> if (typeof pages == 'undefined' || !pages) {
>           var pages = {};
>       }
>
> ```
>     pages.carrierInformation = (function () {
>         var bindAccordion = function () {
>             $('#accordion').accordion({
>                 autoHeight: false
>             });
>         };
>
>         return {
>             init: function () {
>                 bindAccordion();
>             }
>         }
>     })();
> ```
>
> **});**

Comment: The code already has a document ready on the carrer info page.  It is what initializes the pages.carrierInformation.init();